# Animating the size of subviews

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

Let's say I have a standard UIView to show my screen. Within that is another UIView, which itself contains three buttons:

```
--------------------------
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|   -------------------  |
|   |  1  |  2  |  3  |  |  UIView A
|   |     |     |     |  |  contains UIView B
|   -------------------  |  which contains 3 buttons.
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
--------------------------
```

I'd like to be able to animate these buttons onto the screen, by starting the button block small in the center, and then 'exploding' bigger. I know I could animate each button individually, but how could I do it just using UIView B. Is there a way that the buttons could automatically resize according to the size of UIView B when animating?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the `autoresizingMask` attribute on the three buttons, to have flexible margins, height and width, so that they "grow" with UIView B as you change the size of UIView B